# Show exact error messages in wso2 Authentication Endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using wso2 authentication endpoint.When user account is locked or if the user doesnt exist or any other error in endpoint we are just getting username password invalid , while in wso2 logs i am getting the exact end point.I tried

```
 <Parameter name="showAuthFailureReason">true</Parameter>
```

but it still throws the default error messsage . Is there any configuration to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

when you enable showAuthFailureReason to true, it sends exact error code as query param authentication endpoint webApp. You have to customize the webApp to show custom error messages based on the error codes [1].

Thanks
Isura

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+Error+Messages

Comment: I am receiving error code only when user does not exist 17001.For invalid credentials or account lock i am not receiving any error code in query parameters

Comment: Did you enable Identity Management Event Listener? You need to enable listeners to work account lock and faildLoginAttemps count